# How use php with ms-dos to print local files

Tags: php

I trying print same text through php script

the print is send to `lpt1` port but the text only go out after windows logoff session or restart the system, 
i am using `xampp` on `windows XP`, and when i do this command(by apache/php) all other print send by others machines to this printer stay in standby, only print out when pc restart or logoff.

when i try print using cmd.exe(ms-dos terminal) all work fine!
the problem is when i use php, then all services to this printer stop.

here is the code using in ms-dos terminal and this work fine!

```
# net use lpt1: \\192.168.1.45\GenericT 
# type file.txt > lpt1
```

here is my php code basic the same code but work after logoff or restart system

```
# $use   = system("net use lpt1: \\192.168.1.45\GenericT",$result);
# $print = system("type file.txt > lpt1",$result2);
```

i try use `exec, shell_exec`.

any ideas? if i try use `linux`

Answer (score 0):

a quicky solution for me was using file_put_contents() function, it is simple, but i'm working to make it better doing another way to print it.