# How to Connect to Zebra Printer ZD220 or Gc420t and print?

Tags: php, printing, zebra-printers, zpl

I have a task at hand that is proving to be difficult. I've been on it for the past few days.
I need to print Mercado Livre's (which is sort of an Amazon) shipment labels from my system directly to my zebra printer. My system is in PHP and I get the labels from their API.
The thing is, I can't for the life of me get my computer to connect to the printer.

At my job, the printer is connected to a desktop connected to my local network via ethernet cable and it is shared.
I can print labels from my laptop, so I know there is a route. How do I find it?

## **What I Have Tried**

Basically, all that I could find on the internet.
I've tried using [robgridley/zebra](https://github.com/robgridley/zebra) PHP ZPL Builder, as well as several others I could find, with no sucess.

**I have tried the following codes:**

When I try this one,

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
    /* Get the port for the service. */ $port = 9100;
    
    /* Get the IP address for the target host. */ $host = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"; //this is the address of the computer that the printer is connected
    
    /* construct the label */ $label = "^XA ^LH0,0 ^FO4,2 ^GB804,798,4 ^FS ^FO4,2 ^GB548,52,4 ^FS ^FO19,12 ^ADN,36,20 ^FDRossi Andrea ^FS ^FO548,2 ^GB260,52,4 ^FS ^FO561,16 ^ADN,36,10 ^FDP/V ^FS ^FO611,16 ^ADN,36,10 ^FD1:3 ^FS ^FO693,16 ^ADN,36,10 ^FD18/12/14 ^FS ^FO20,66 ^GB540,135,80 ^FS ^FO21,70 ^ADN,135,25 ^FR ^FDREGGIO CALABRIA ^FS ^FO720,66 ^GB72,135,80 ^FS ^FO721,70 ^ADN,135,25 ^FR ^FD13 ^FS ^FO4,210 ^GB128,166,4 ^FS ^FO128,210 ^GB680,166,4 ^FS ^FO136,220 ^ADN,36,15 ^FDProva Rossi ^FS ^FO136,276 ^ADN,36,10 ^FDCONTRADA RAVAGNESE GRAZIELLA,8 ^FS ^FO15,243 ^ADN,108,50 ^FDE5 ^FS ^FO136,338 ^ADN,36,14 ^FDReggio Calabria ^FS ^FO580,338 ^ADN,36,15 ^FDRC ^FS ^FO632,210 ^GB176,166,4 ^FS ^FO660,220 ^AAN,18,5 ^FDCALABRIA SICILIA ^FS ^FO695,246 ^ADN,18,5 ^FDCSN ^FS ^FO632, 273 ^GB176,103,4 ^FS ^FO640,280 ^ADN,18,5 ^FDPeso Kg ^FS ^FO680,318 ^ADN,36,20 ^FD4.1 ^FS ^FO632, 372 ^GB176,48,4 ^FS ^FO640,378 ^ADN,18,5 ^FDPorto: ^FS ^FO658,398 ^ADN,18,10 ^FDFRANCO ^FS ^FO4,372 ^GB804,48,4 ^FS ^FO25,383 ^ADN,36,10 ^FDNote: ^FS ^FO88,383 ^ADN,36,10 ^FDProva Zaffignani ^FS ^FO640,650 ^XGE:GLSMINI.GRF,1,1 ^FS ^FO606,718 ^GB202,82,4 ^FS ^FO4,718 ^GB606,82,4 ^FS ^FO240,718 ^GB144,80,40 ^FS ^FO242,724 ^ADN,96,25 ^FR ^FD1-25 ^FS ^FO50,422 ^BY3 ^BCN,260,N,N,N,A ^FVWW540006975010RC ^FS ^FO50,685 ^ADN,27,15 ^FDWW 540006975 01 0 RC 01 ^FS ^XZ";
    
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP); echo "<pre>"; echo "Socket: " . $socket; if ($socket === false) {
        echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n"; } else {
        echo "\nOK. \n"; }
    
    echo "Attempting to connect to '$host' on port '$port'..."; $result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);
    
    echo $result; if ($result === false) {
        echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n"; } else {
        echo "OK.\n"; }
    
    socket_write($socket, $label, strlen($label)); socket_close($socket);
```

I get this response

```
Socket: Resource id #2
OK. 
Attempting to connect to 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx' on port '9100'...

Warning:  socket_connect(): unable to connect [110]: Connection timed out in /xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx on line 38

socket_connect() failed.
Reason: () Connection timed out


Warning:  socket_write(): unable to write to socket [32]: Broken pipe in /xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx on line 47
```

I know for a fact that port 445 is open (via netstat on said computer).
So I changed the port to 445 and send the command to print.

```
Socket: Resource id #2
OK. 
Attempting to connect to 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx' on port '445'...1OK.
```

Unfortunately, nothing is printed.
The following code returns nothing at all, for some reason.

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("xxx.xxx.xx.xx", 445, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)
\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: xxx.xxx.xx.xx\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        echo fgets($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose($fp);
}


echo "</pre>";
```

I tried a lot of other codes but it's basically the same thing (socket_create and fsockopen).
I have tried exec with my printer's name:

```
exec("lpr -P '\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\ZDesigner ZD220-203dpi ZPL' -r 'README.txt');
```

and

```
exec("lp -d '\\xxx.xxx.xx.xx\ZDesigner ZD220-203dpi ZPL' -r 'README.txt');
```

As I was writing this, I felt bold and tested 20000 ports from 1 to 20000 with this code:

```
<?php
$host = 'xxx.xxx.xx.xx';

for($i = 1; $i <= 20000; $i++) {
    $connection = @fsockopen($host, $i);

    if (is_resource($connection)) {
        echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $i . ' ' . '(' . getservbyport($i, 'tcp') . ') is open.</h2>' . "\n";

        fclose($connection);
    } else {
    echo '<h2>' . $host . ':' . $i . ' is not responding.</h2>' . "\n";
    }
}
```

That was a stupid move, as it took a lot of time and returned me what I already knew. Some ports are open, but 9100 isn't.
I opened up ports 23 (for telnet), 515 and 9100 on firewall, that didn't get me anywhere, it still says connection timeout. When I completely deactive windows firewall on the desktop, it says connection refused.
When I try to send commands to the printer via it's settings, it gives me CM:OpenPrinter Access Denied.
Zebra also has a setup utilities tool, which wasn't giving me this error but today it is:

[image: New Error]

Also, when I send ~WL it says no network installed, which okay, I know, but there is some way, because otherwise I wouldn't be able to print anything.

## **What I Need:**

Is there any way I can access the printer via PHP?
I really need it to work. Thank you for taking the time to read this.
I've tried my best to formulate this question, I hope I didn't end up being confusing.

Comment: What are the socket connections for? It seems fairly unlikely the printer itself nor Windows provides a working PrintJet interface. Why not `NET USE LPT1: \\srv\share` a virtual port?

Comment: I think I didn't get to that point. Of all my researches on the topic, I didn't come across that. Could you elaborate a bit more? I used socket connections because it seems to be what people usually do.

Comment: Good suggestion by @mario! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763890/how-use-php-with-ms-dos-to-print-local-files might help you get further

Comment: Update: I've managed to use net use lpt1 to the printer on the command prompt. But when I send a file to print, it keeps sending the data to the spool, and being a "Remote Downlevel Document" for some reason. Unfortunately, I'm only going to work on this again on monday. Thank you for the help, I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

We use `fputs($fp, $out)` instead of `fwrite($fp, $out)`, with `$out` being some EZPL/ZPL code in a string.

```php
$fp = fsockopen($printer['ip'], $printer['port'], $errno, $errstr, 10);
if (!$fp) {
    // code if no connection found
} else {
    $out = "some EZPL code as string";
    fputs($fp, $out);
    fclose($fp);
}
```